# select and display empty column in case one condition at where clause is not met (because of non-existent element at other table)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 Tables, the table1 and table2.

```
Table1 has columns P_KEY, ID, some_value, some_value2, ....
Table2 has columns P2_KEY, RELATED_DATA, F_KEY, DATA_VALUE.
```

P_KEY and ID of table1 are unique pairs.
For each P_KEY (and thus each ID) of table1 there are multiple F_KEY entries of table2 with various data of each ID.
The RELATED_DATA rows have specific values (from a defined range elsewhere), which define the kind of Data stored for each ID.
I need to select the DATA_VALUE of ID where RELATED_DATA is 1 and 500. If one of them or both do not exist, I still want to display the row with (examples):

```
ID, DATA_VALUE (where RELATED_DATA=500), <empty column>
ID, <empty column>, DATA_VALUE (where RELATED_DATA=1)
ID, <empty column>, <empty column>
ID, DATA_VALUE (where RELATED_DATA=500), DATA_VALUE (where RELATED_DATA=1)
```

I have an SQL like the below, and I need to display row for A.ID, even when B1.RELATED_DATA and/or B2.RELATED_DATA do NOT exist (no row entry at table2), or this is empty string, having the B1.DATA_VALUE and/or B2.DATA_VALUE cell(s) showing as empty cell(s):

```
select A.ID, B1.DATA_VALUE, B2.DATA_VALUE
from table1 A, table2 B1, table2 B2 
where B1.F_KEY = A.P_KEY
and B2.F_KEY = A.P_KEY
and B1.RELATED_DATA = 500
and B2.RELATED_DATA = 1
and A.ID='OneValue';
```

Purpose is to know the cases at which when B1.RELATED_DATA=500 and/or B2.RELATED_DATA=1 row do not exist or they are empty strings for ID.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you'd need to do is to pivot the rows in table2 to get the two data_values as columns, rather than rows. Then you can join that back to table1 like so:

```
select a.id,
       b.data_value_500,
       b.data_value_1
from   table1 a
       inner join (select   f_key,
                            max(case when related_data = 500 then data_value end) data_value_500,
                            max(case when related_data = 1 then data_value end) data_value_1
                   from     table2
                   group by f_key) b on (a.p_key = b.f_key)
where  a.id = 'OneValue';
```

N.B. I've used an `inner join` under the assumption that there will always be a row present in table2 for each p_key in table1. If that's not the case, switch to a `left outer join` instead.

---

Also, if you're on Oracle 11g or above, it's possible to use the built in PIVOT functionality to do the pivoting of table2:

```
select a.id,
       b.data_value_500,
       b.data_value_1
from   table1 a
       inner join (select f_key,
                          data_value_1,
                          data_value_500
                   from   table2
                   pivot (max(data_value) for related_data in (1 as data_value_1,
                                                               500 as data_value_500)))
where  a.id = 'OneValue';
```